# PyQt accessing Label and LineEdit that are dynamically created

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to access dynamically created Labels and LineEdit to change their texts.

I have no idea how is that possible ?

As an example, when **Start** button is clicked it should change the text of `PS1 QLineEdit` from `XXXX` to `YYYY` .

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("BiPolar Power Supply Testing")
        widget_map = {}

        tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(tab_widget)

        pstest_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        tab_widget.addTab(pstest_widget, "PS Tests")

        pstest_vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()        

        for i in range(1, 9):
            title = "PS{}".format(i)
            group_box = MainWindow.create_pstest_element(title)
            pstest_vlay.addWidget(group_box)

        self.PSFStart_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.PSFStop_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop")
        pstest_vlay.addWidget(self.PSFStart_btn)
        pstest_vlay.addWidget(self.PSFStop_btn)
        pstest_vlay.addStretch()

        grid_lay_1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(pstest_widget)
        #grid_lay_1.addWidget(pstest_widget)
        grid_lay_1.addLayout(pstest_vlay, 0, 0)

    @staticmethod
    def create_pstest_element(title):
        group_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(title)
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()        

        serial_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Serial No:")
        serial_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("XXXX")

        grid.addWidget(serial_label, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(serial_lineedit, 0, 1)

        group_box.setLayout(grid)
        return group_box

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()   
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is how the GUI looks like:

[image: GUI Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current design makes it difficult to access the widgets since you do not save access to the elements (you could use a filter using findChildren but that method is not scalable or elegant.).

In these cases it is better than creating a class that inherits from QGroupBox by making internal elements such as the QLabel and QLineEdit class members. On the other hand, having many QGroupBox, it is best to use a container that allows us to access each element by means of an index or key, in this one a list is enough.

```py
class GroupBox(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super().__init__(title, parent)
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.serial_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Serial No:")
        self.serial_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("XXXX")

        grid.addWidget(self.serial_label, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.serial_lineedit, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(grid)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("BiPolar Power Supply Testing")

        tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(tab_widget)

        pstest_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        tab_widget.addTab(pstest_widget, "PS Tests")

        pstest_vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.group_boxes = []

        for i in range(1, 9):
            title = "PS{}".format(i)
            group_box = GroupBox(title)
            pstest_vlay.addWidget(group_box)
            self.group_boxes.append(group_box)

        self.PSFStart_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.PSFStop_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop")
        pstest_vlay.addWidget(self.PSFStart_btn)
        pstest_vlay.addWidget(self.PSFStop_btn)
        pstest_vlay.addStretch()

        grid_lay_1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(pstest_widget)
        # grid_lay_1.addWidget(pstest_widget)
        grid_lay_1.addLayout(pstest_vlay, 0, 0)

        self.PSFStart_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_start_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_start_clicked(self):
        group_box = self.group_boxes[0]
        group_box.serial_lineedit.setText("YYYY")
```